# Face a error in project, When I implement Applovin MAX interstatial ad

Tags: java, android-studio, admob, ads, applovin

I don't understand the error in project.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Then come back and [edit] your question accordingly. You might also want to read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful) and you definitely should elaborate _why_ you're not understanding this error (it seems to be a type mismatch which you should be able to understand at least on a basic level).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to provide an AppCompatDialogFragment as an Activity. Trying use `getActivity()` instead of `this` may fix the problem